# VBA EXCEL: Apply sub to another worksheet from module

Tags: excel, vba, methods

Trying to get a sub from a module to run within another worksheet. In a sense to stop using redundant ranges and keep it streamlined.

```
i.e.
-Module object-
Public sub method1()
{
  Range("B4:B23") = ""
  Range("C4:C23") = ""
  'Empties these ranges...
}
-worksheet(s)-
sub project)
{
with sheet1 (or on any sheet 2,3,4,5... etc.)
Call module1.method1 
'but this method only works on the module object, not in the context of the 'specified worksheet where it is needed
End with
```

Ideally to clear the data in ranges by using method1 in ANY worksheet. Every reference I tried just runs the module1 method without any effect or makes a useless reference to the method or worksheet. Just trying to save on code space by not writing direct references to every sheet which is formatted identical.

Comment: Just Record a Macro and tweak the code to make it reusable

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a sub (`ClearCells`) that accepts a variable number of arguments via the `ParamArray` keyword.  Then you can simply call the `ClearCells` sub and pass it the worksheet objects you want to clear the same ranges in, as in the `DoClear` sub.  You can add more ranges as needed to the `Union` function in the `GetRanges` function.

```
Sub DoClear()

    ClearCells Sheet1, Sheet3

End Sub


Sub ClearCells(ParamArray wkshts() As Variant)

    Dim vWs As Variant
    Dim ws  As Worksheet

    For Each vWs In wkshts
        Set ws = vWs
        GetRanges(ws).Clear
    Next vWs

End Sub

Function GetRanges(ws As Worksheet) As Range

    With ws
        Set GetRanges = Union(.Range("B4:B23"), _
                            .Range("C4:C23"))
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Or assuming you are calling the method from the sheet you want to clear, you can just use ActiveSheet:

```
Public Sub Method1()
    ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B23").Clear
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C23").Clear
End Sub
```